# How to keep pictures sent in Facebook messenger from saving to your Droid MAXX?

Tags: facebook-messenger

Pictures sent to me on Facebook Messenger are automatically saved. How do I keep this from happening?

Please help

Answer (score 1):

Open the settings tab (the rightmost tab on Messenger), and there you will find option "Save incoming photos to your Gallery"

[image]